# ORACLE SQL DEVELOPER-select count(*) from multiple databases

Tags: oracle, count, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I select count(*) from two different databases(call them ZEOTA and SP) having as result:

```
Zeota SP
  88  3
```

I have tried this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CONSTRAINT_TYPE) NumberOfPrimaryKeys_Zeota 
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P' 
AND 
OWNER = 'ZEOTA';
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberOfAttributes_SP
FROM ALL_COL_COMMENTS
WHERE OWNER = 'SP';
```

But the output shows two separate query results:

```
Query result 1: 
    Zeota
      88
Query Result 2:
      SP
      3
```

However I am trying to do it this way, but having issues:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME) AS ZNumOfTables,
COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME) AS SNumOfTables,
COUNT(DISTINCT TABLE_NAME) AS PNumOfTables
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE OWNER = 'SP';
WHERE OWNER = 'ZEOTA';
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use your current queries as CTEs and then just cross join them:

```
with
t1 as 
  (select count(constraint_type) num_pk_zeota
   from all_constraints
   where owner = 'ZEOTA'
     and constraint_type = 'PK'
  ),
t2 as
  (select count(*) num_attr_sp
   from all_col_comments
   where owner = 'SP'
  )
select a.num_pk_zeota,
       b.num_attr_sp
from t1 a cross join t2 b;
```

P.S. What you call "databases" are **users** (schemas) in Oracle.

Comment: Thank you! Now I am in the process of adding more "Users" but am having trouble with the last select statement. This is what I have for the cross join,                                                                        "from t1 a cross join t2 b and t3 c cross join t4 d;" I am getting a "SQL Command not properly ended"

Comment: It's just `from t1 a cross join t2 b cross join t3 c`